# What does this function (convert_to_command) do?

Tags: python, regex

This is code. Can someone elaborate pls?

```
import re

from unidecode import unidecode

pattern = re.compile('[^\w ,]+', re.UNICODE)


def convert_to_command(text):
    return '/' + re.sub(r'[, ]', '_', pattern.sub('', unidecode(text.lower())))
```

Comment: You should start breaking it down into parts and add the result to the question. Like this your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

```
pattern = re.compile('[^\w ,]+', re.UNICODE)    
'/' + re.sub(r'[, ]', '_', pattern.sub('', unidecode(text.lower())))
```

- unidecode : It will decode the uni string first
- pattern.sub : It will remove all the characters except word characters such as "a-z", "A-Z", "0-9" and "_" and "," and " "
- re.sub : It will substitute all the "," and " " to "_"
- "/" : This part prepends "/ character to the string.